# Qual a origem da palavra "ônibus"?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica

Qual a origem da palavra "ônibus"?
Vem do Brasil?

Em Portugal não é utilizada, usamos a palavra "autocarro".
Também utilizamos "Carreira", possivelmente um regionalismo
Na Madeira também é conhecido por Horário

Comment: Tentaste ver no dicionário? Todos os que conheço, online, têm a origem etimológica das palavras...

Comment: Acho que essas preguntas deveriam se fechar....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Certamente que não teve sua origem no Brasil.

A palavra tem sua origem no Latim "omnibus", tanto que em Inglês existe a palavra "omnibus" (fora de uso há tempos) e que foi abreviada para "bus". E, nos diversos países de língua portuguesa, o ônibus tem suas denominações locais.

> - ônibus (português brasileiro)
> - autocarro (português europeu)
> - machimbombo (português angolano e moçambicano)
> - toca-toca(português cabo-verdiano),
> - microlete (português timorense)
>
> A designação dos veículos de transporte de passageiros varia de país para país e até mesmo de região para região. **Várias das designações têm origem da palavra "omnibus" ("para todos" em latim).** Este termo foi usado, desde o século XIX, para designar um tipo de transporte coletivo de passageiros puxado a cavalo, usado nas grandes cidades do mundo, com caraterísticas e funções muito semelhantes aos transportes coletivos atuais.
>
> **No Brasil, os transportes coletivos de passageiros são designados "ônibus", termo originado diretamente em "omnibus".**
>
> Em Portugal, até a década de 1940, foi usado o termo "auto-ómnibus", referindo-se a um > ómnibus automóvel. A partir de então, foi introduzido o termo "autocarro", também se utilizando popularmente o termo "camioneta" para designar os autocarros interurbanos.
> Em Angola e Moçambique, usa-se o termo "machimbombo", com origem no nome popular que se dava ao Elevador da Estrela, em Lisboa (1890-1913), e que se se supõe ser uma adaptação do inglês "machine pump".
> Na Guiné-Bissau, Cabo Verde e São Tomé e Príncipe usam-se os termos "toca-toca" e "otocarro", derivados de "autocarro".
> Em Timor-Leste aos pequenos autocarros dá-se a designação de "microlete".
> Internacionalmente, também é utilizado o termo "bus" (redução de "omnibus") ou o termo "autobus"  [**Wikipedia**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%94nibus)